# Как в VS Code сделать отступ 2 символа вместо 4 символов автоматическому выравниванию при сохранении JS файла

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

Новая система. Дефолтный VS Code. Специально никаких настроек не делал.

Установил отступ в 2 пробела. Также включена замена Tab на 2 пробела.

[image: VS Code user options]

[image: VS Code workspace options]

Подключил Prettier. Пока пишешь код, работает как надо.

Принудительное выравнивание по горячим клавишам тоже работает как надо.

Но при сохранении файла, файл выравнивается с отступами 4 пробела вместо 2.

Я помню эту проблему (не первый раз), что-то где-то менял, но не помню что и где.

Как сделать так, чтобы VS Code при сохранении выравнивал отступы по 2 пробелам?

[image: VS code prettier in action]

**UPDATE**

В настройках Prettier **Tab size** указан **2**. Как в настройках User, так и в настройках Workspace.

[image: Prettier options]

Перегрузил настройку в проекте.

[image: VS Code project settings]

**UPDATE2**

Ничего не помогает. Опытным путём замечено, что проблема проявляется только в JS-файлах. Все остальные файлы (С/С++/JSON/JAVA) сохраняются с отступами в 2 пробела.

Comment: Посмотрите [.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/)

Comment: Тоже сейчас столкнулась с такой же проблемой. У вас получилось найти решение?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в плагине [JS-CSS-HTML formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter&ssr=false#overview)

Я даже не помню, я ли установил этот плагин?! Или этот треш стоял по дефолту?!

В любом случае, при похожих симптомах сначала удалите этот плагин, а потом разбирайтесь в настройках дальше.